# In Python how do I plot using GMPY2?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm not new to programming, but I am new to Python and numerical computing, so this may be a newbie question.

I'm using GMPY2 to handle computation of extremely large numbers, but I want to use MatPlotLib to graph the results. I currently have

```
import gmpy2
from gmpy2 import mpz, mpq, mpfr, mpc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


gmpy2.get_context().precision = 100


def hop(x, y, n):
    if n > 0:
        return gmpy2.exp(hop(gmpy2.log(x), gmpy2.log(y), n-1))
    elif n == 0:
        return gmpy2.add(x, y)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Negative value of n in hop method.')


t = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.01)
plt.plot(t, hop(t, t, 0))
```

I assume there's no implicit conversion from mpfr to numpy's native type. In `np.arange` I tried setting `dtype=mpfr`, and also in the `plot` method I tried writing `hop(mpfr(t), mpfr(t), 0)`, but of course no luck.

Comment: In your case, I'll use only numpy and matplotlib because numpy let to handle large numbers. Unfortunately I don't know gmpy2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.

Since you didn't state your error message, I tried your code and encountered the following error message:

```
TypeError: add() argument types not supported
```

The `gmpy2` functions only accept scalar arguments. They do not iterate over a list. You will need to do that manually.

```
t = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.01)
hopt = [hop(x, x, 0) for x in t]
plt.plot(t, hopt)
```

Update

Here is an example showing an `mpfr_range()` function.

```
import gmpy2
from gmpy2 import mpfr, exp, log

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gmpy2.get_context().precision = 100

def mpfr_range(first, last, n):
    '''Yield a sequence of n mpfr values that range from first
    to last. Both first and last are included. n must be greater
    than or equal to 2.'''

    n = int(n)
    first = mpfr(first)
    last = mpfr(last)

    if n < 2:
        raise ValueError('n must be >= 2')

    if last <= first:
        raise ValueError('last must be > first')

    delta = (last - first) / (n - 1)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        yield first + i * delta

    yield last

def hop(x, y, n):
    if n > 0:
        return exp(hop(log(x), log(y), n-1))
    elif n == 0:
        return x + y
    else:
        raise ValueError('Negative value of n in hop method.')

# It is recommended to initialize mpfr instances from exact values -
# either a string or an integer for this use.
t = list(mpfr_range('10', '20', 20))

hopt = [hop(x, x, 0) for x in t]
plt.plot(t, hopt)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm! One last question -- I'd like to have this code ready to handle much larger domains, e.g. [10^100, 2*10^200]. I assume numpy.arange isn't really suitable for this. What's the best way to get gmpy2 to handle all the numbers from start to finish here?